# Iterative deepening depth-first search heuristics to solve "3 Missionary And Cannibal" challenge

Tags: c++, ai, depth-first-search

[Missionaries and cannibals problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missionaries_and_cannibals_problem)  is a well known Toy Problem to learn basic AI techniques.

I implemented it using iterative deepening depth-first search algorithm. My state is represented by a 3-element vector `<A,B,C>` where `A` represents the side of the boat (0/1), B and C represents the number of cannibals and missionary on the left hand side of the bank.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
/*
SOLUTION TO 3 CANNIBAL and 3 MISSIONARIES PROBLEM 
USING ITERATIVE DEEPENING DEPTH FIRST SEARCH
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missionaries_and_cannibals_problem
*/

//state initial state (0,3,3) Side Of the Boat 0->Right/1 /Cannibal/Missionary on right hand side 
vector < pair < int, pair<int,int> > > newStatesSet(pair< int, pair < int, int > > state){
  //generating all possible states from a given initial state
  vector < pair< int, pair< int, int> > > newStatesSet;
  int C = state.second.first, M = state.second.second;

  if(state.first==0){
    if(C>=1)
      newStatesSet.push_back(make_pair(1, make_pair( C-1 ,M  )));
    if(M>=1)
      newStatesSet.push_back(make_pair(1, make_pair( C   ,M-1)));
    if(C >= 2)
      newStatesSet.push_back(make_pair(1, make_pair( C-2, M   )));
    if(C >= 1 && M >=1 )
      newStatesSet.push_back(make_pair(1, make_pair( C-1, M-1 )));
    if(M >= 2)
      newStatesSet.push_back(make_pair(1, make_pair( C  , M-2 )));
  }
  else{
    C = 3- C;
    M = 3- M;

    if(C >= 1)
      newStatesSet.push_back(make_pair(0, make_pair(3- C+ 1 ,3- M  )));
    if(M >= 1)
      newStatesSet.push_back(make_pair(0, make_pair(3- C   ,3- M+ 1)));
    if(C >= 2)
      newStatesSet.push_back(make_pair(0, make_pair(3- C+ 2, 3- M   )));
    if(C >= 1 && M >=1 )
      newStatesSet.push_back(make_pair(0, make_pair(3- C+ 1, 3- M+ 1 )));
    if(M >= 2)
      newStatesSet.push_back(make_pair(0, make_pair(3- C  , 3- M+ 2)));
  }
  return newStatesSet;
}

bool validState(pair<int, pair<int, int> > state){
  int C = state.second.first, M = state.second.second;
  if(C > M && M!=0)
    return false;
  C = 3- C, M = 3- M;
  if(C > M && M!=0)
    return false;
  return true;
}

//source node , goal node , depth , answer if found is stored here
bool  depthLimitedSearch(pair<int, pair<int, int> > source, pair<int, pair<int, int> > goal, int depth, vector<pair<int, pair<int,int> > > &ans){

  if(source==goal)
    return true;

  if(depth<=0)
    return false;

  vector <pair<int, pair<int,int> > > leafs = newStatesSet(source);
  for(int i=0; i<leafs.size(); i++)
    if(validState(leafs[i])){
      if(depthLimitedSearch(leafs[i], goal, depth-1, ans)){
        ans.push_back(leafs[i]);
        return true;
      }
    }
}

string form(int stateNos,string character){
  string rep="";
  for(int i=1; i<=3; i++)
    if(stateNos>=i)
      rep.append(character);
    else
      rep.append(" ");
  return rep;
}

void displayState(pair<int, pair<int, int> > state){
  string rep = "";
  rep.append(form(state.second.first,"C"));
  rep.append(form(state.second.second,"M"));
  for(int i=1; i<=6; i++){
    if(state.first==0 && i==2)
      rep.append("B");
    else
    if(state.first==1 && i==5)
      rep.append("B");
    else
      rep.append(" ");
  }
  rep.append(form(3-state.second.first,"C"));
  rep.append(form(3-state.second.second,"M"));
  cout<<rep<<endl;
}

void iterativeDeepeningSearch(pair<int, pair<int, int> > source, pair<int, pair<int, int> > goal){

  vector< pair<int , pair<int, int> > > ans;
  for(int i=1 ; i <= 25 ;i++){
    vector<pair<int, pair<int, int> > >vec;
    depthLimitedSearch(source,goal,i,vec);
    if(vec.size()>0){
      ans=vec;
      break;
    }
  }
  cout<<"C and M represents cannibals and Missionaries \n respectively and B represents the location of boat\n";
  displayState(source);
  for(int i=ans.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
    displayState(ans[i]);
}

int main()
{ 
  pair<int, pair<int, int> > source = make_pair(0,make_pair(3, 3 ));
  pair<int, pair<int, int> > goal   = make_pair(1,make_pair(0, 0 ));
  iterativeDeepeningSearch(source,goal);
}
```

[The code can also be found here](https://github.com/imrandomizer/common-programs/blob/master/3Missionary3CannibalProblem_IDDFS.cpp).

It produces the following output:

> ```
> CCCMMM B          
> C  MMM    B CC    
> CC MMM B    C     
>    MMM    B CCC   
> C  MMM B    CC    
> C  M      B CC MM 
> CC MM  B    C  M  
> CC        B C  MMM
> CCC    B       MMM
> C         B CC MMM
> CC     B    C  MMM
>           B CCCMMM
> ```

What do you think is wrong with this code, and how can it be improved? What edge cases have I overlooked, if any? How can I make it less complicated?

Comment: Is this not a bad state? `C  M      B CC MM ` Seems lime the M on the left back is being eaten.

Comment: No,
If the number of C's and M's are equal on any side then it is considered a good state. Ie  Nos(C)== Nos(M) is a good state.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, do *not* use namespace::std. Please google for it, you will find a lot of answers.

---

Please include all the necessary headers. A first glance tells me that the following is missing:

```
#include <string> // std::string
#include <utility> // std::pair
#include <vector> // std::vector
```

---

Why are you using pair>? Have a look at tuples: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple/

```
std::tuple<bool, size_t, size_t>
```

---

Have a look at your function arguments and declare those const who are not modified. Also you are always passing a copy rather a reference so you should either be dooing one of the following.

```
foo(const type &bar)
foo(type &bar)
```

---

Try to add a space between control flow instructions like `for`, `while` and friends. Therewith you can readily differentiate them from functions.

---

Depending on the C++ version you are using you want to consider using range based loops for C++11 and higher. Then a loop like this one:

```
vector <pair<int, pair<int,int> > > leafs = newStatesSet(source);
for(int i=0; i<leafs.size(); i++)
    if(validState(leafs[i])) {
        if(depthLimitedSearch(leafs[i], goal, depth-1, ans)){
            ans.push_back(leafs[i]);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

becomes this

```
std::vector<std::tuple<bool, size_t, size_t> > leafs = newStatesSet(source);
for (auto &leaf : leafs)
    if (validState(leaf)) {
        if (depthLimitedSearch(leaf, goal, depth-1, ans)){
            ans.push_back(leaf);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

If you need the index often or reverse loops, then use iterators

```
for (int i=ans.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
    displayState(ans[i]);
```

then becomes

```
for (auto it=ans.rbegin(); it != ans.rend(); ++it) 
    displayState(*it);
```

---

More a personal thing than anything else but still. Your if ladders are really confusing. Whenever i see stuff like

```
if (C >= 1)
    // Stuff C==1
if (C >= 2)
    // Stuff C>=1
```

I cringe inwardly. In that setting it is really easy to miss the first clause for C >= 2. So why not do

```
if (C == 1)
    // Stuff C==1
else if (C >= 2)
    // Stuff C==1
    // Stuff C>=1
```

I know it is repetitive, but at least the control flow is really clear.